# Cannot join on autocad student version

Tags: autocad

I have made a gear and I have arc and array. I should combine and join them to one line because I should extrude it after that. I've tried everything I can, but it says "0 objects joined, 2 objects discard the operation". I've tried selecting the arc and the array and after that entering the command "join". Then the same message displays. I've also tried writing the command join after which selecting the arc and the array and last pressing enter. But every time and -any way the same message dysplays!

I've also made an animation for you to see what I'm doing:

[image: Animation HERE]

Any help will be MUCH appreciated. I lose 2 hours for searching how to solve this and nothing helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot join objects to an Array in AutoCAD. The new Array object introduced in more recent versions of AutoCAD (2013?) is actually represented using an anonymous block reference and therefore cannot be joined to any other object.

You will first need to explode the array (using the `EXPLODE` command) and then either use the `JOIN` command on the resulting objects, or use `PEDIT > MULTIPLE > JOIN` to join the objects to form a single continuous 2D polyline, which if closed, may be then be extruded.